# Бегающий за курсором объект

Tags: javascript

```js
var dL = dT = 0,
  L = 111,
  T = 111;
O = document.getElementById('obj').style;
var mouseX = window.event.clientX,
  mouseY = window.event.clientY;
onload = function() {
  window.event = function(ev) {
    var X, Y;
    ev = window.event;
    X = O.left;
    Y = O.top;
    if (ev.clientX != mouseX) {
      dL = ev.clientX - mouseX;
      X = X + dL;
      mouseX = ev.clientX;
    }
    if (ev.clientY != mouseY) {
      dT = ev.clientY - mouseY;
      Y = Y + dT;
      mouseY = ev.clientY;
    }


  }

  function move() {
    var p = 'px';
    O.left = X + p;
    O.top = Y + p;
    setTimeout(move, 100);
  }
  move();
}
```

```css
#obj {
  width: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="obj" style="position : relative; left : 111px; top : 111px;"></div>
```

почему объект не бегает за курсором мыши? В чем ошибка?

Comment: window.event по вашему что такое ?

Comment: событие в окне...если я не ошибаюсь. А что должно быть?

Comment: это из ie, - переменная котороя содержит описание состоявшегося события (то что у вас ev) но это редко используется,

> When a handler gets called, it gets an Event object as its first argument, which has lots of fields that describe about the event, such as which keystroke was hit, what the mouse coordinates were, the time at which the event happened, and so on. Only Internet Explorer versions lower than 9 uses the global window.event object instead of an argument. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events

Comment: Как сюда кинуть исправленный код?
Или дайте ссылку на песочницу щас туда закину

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net ну и в вопросе исправьте, чтобы если будет ответ он таки на него отвечал.

Comment: Мне результат не выводит...(( Что-то я там делаю не так...

Comment: А нет, я тупанул, кнопочку Run не заметил)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BxbCZ/ вот, посмотрите.

Comment: [вот ваш вопрос в jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/AJBD2/)

Answer (score 3):

всё неправильно, во первых window.onmousemove, во вторых, раз вы в заголовке заявляете html5, то значит про старые браузеры не думаем, поэтому windown.addEventListener,

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () { //все в один блок, т.к. вам же надо получить #obj ?
    //console.log(1);
    /* 
    это не нужно
    dL = 0,
        dT = 0, //обявление dL=dT=0 не работает!
        */
    var O = document.getElementById('obj'),
        X = 0,
        Y = 0,mouseX=0,mouseY=0; //надо  объявлять X/Y здесь, т.к они используются за пределами замыкания обработчика
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (ev) {
        ev = window.event || ev; //если window.event определен, то это IE<9, поддерживаем 
        X=ev.pageX;
        Y=ev.pageY;
        /* //всё это не нужно, а если нужно, то неправильно рассчитано, если вых хотите чтобы объект плавно бегал за курсором, то вам нужно просто знак посчитать и прибавлять шаги к X,Y 
        X = O.style.left;
        Y = O.style.top;        
        if (ev.pageX != mouseX) {
            dL = ev.pageX - mouseX;
            X = X + dL;
            mouseX = ev.pageX;
        }
        if (ev.pageY != mouseY) {
            dT = ev.pageY - mouseY;
            Y = Y + dT;
            mouseY = ev.pageY; 
        }*/
    });

    function move() { //зачем аргумент ?
        var p = 'px';
        O.style.left = X + p;
        O.style.top = Y + p;

        setTimeout(move, 100);
    }
    move();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/BxbCZ/3/

Answer (score 1):

на вопрос почему не работает не отвечу, какой-то хардкор-стайл...

вот [вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/6gP38/) с transitions.

css:

```
#x {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background: red;
    margin:-25px 0 0 -25px;
    position:absolute;
    transition: top 0.5s, left 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s, left 0.5s;
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var X = Y = 0;

    function move() {
        document.getElementById('x').style.left = X + 'px';
        document.getElementById('x').style.top = Y + 'px';
    }
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        X = e.clientX;
        Y = e.clientY;
    }, false);

    setInterval(move, 100);
});
```

ЗЫ варианты с jquery animate и даже pure javascript расчета анимации будут проигрывать. [пруф](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-vs-jquery-animations/), хотя все давно могло поменяться...

Comment: а это смотря как делать, если не считать в каждом кадре, то может и меньше нагрузка на проц будет.

Comment: @eicto, ну я не проверял. положился на мнение тех, кто проверял. с другой стороны немногословность данного варианта и поддержка во всех модерновых браузерах не дают повода сомневаться в таком решении, тем более `<!DOCTYPE html>`. хром и опера(webkit) гладкостью просто радуют.

Comment: согласен. это пример просто.

Comment: у меня что-то не сработала эта разница http://jsfiddle.net/pYyy6/ , в хроме не работает, а в FF работает.

Comment: угу. у меня в лисе interval вызывается даже чаще при щелкании по вкладкам... будем считать, что тут это не принципиально, сам не люблю интервал.

Comment: > interval вызывается даже чаще

не "даже", а "чуть" чаще. сорри глючу, спать надо больше )

Comment: оно не чаще, а просто все пропущенные интервалы догоняет, в то время как timeOut, только один.